# Display the price of button on button click with a default active price being the first element in the array in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I have a problem that I would appreciate if I get assisted here.I have a button group as shown below:
[image: button group]

I am trying to create a price calculator based on the button click.On page load I want the first button to be active with price displaying in the summary card as shown below:
[image]

**My sample array of elements are as shown below:**

```
AcademicLevels: [
                {
                    id:1,
                    name: 'High School',
                    price: 20,
                    active: true
                },
                {
                    id:2,
                    name: 'Undergrad. (yrs 1‑2)',
                    price: 30,
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    id:3,
                    name: 'Undergrad. (yrs 3‑4)',
                    price: 35,
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    id:4,
                    name: 'Masters',
                    price: 40,
                    active: false
                },
                {
                    id:5,
                    name: 'PHD',
                    price: 50,
                    active: false
                }
            ],
```

**The button group code :**

```
<div class="rc-orderform__row">
   <div class="rc-orderform__feature-heading">Academic level</div>
   <div class="rc-orderform__feature-body">
      <div class="rc-validation-representer valid" data-invalid="false">
         <div class="rc-radios rc-radios--theme-default vertical-on-small"   style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <div class="radio-button-wrapper radio-button-wrapper radio-button-wrapper--flexbuttons"  v-for="academic in AcademicLevels"
               :key="academic.id"
               >
               <button type="button" class="radio-button radio-button--n-1" tabindex="-1"
                  v-on:click="worklevelChanged(academic.id)"
                  :class="academicPriceId===Number(academic.id)? 'active':''"
                  :id="'workLevel_' + academic.id"
                  :value="academic.id"
                  v-model="academicPrice"
                  >
                  <div class="button-checkbox"></div>
                  <div class="radio-button__content">{{academic.name}}</div>
               </button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**The Percentage Cost Calculator Method**

```
methods: {
       
        calculatePercentage(basePrice,percentageToAdd){
            var number= (parseFloat(basePrice)* parseFloat(percentageToAdd))/100;
            return Number(parseFloat(number));

        }

    },
```

**The Total Cost Calculator Method**

```
computed:{

        calculateTotal : function (){
            var workLevelModel = this.AcademicLevels;
            var base_price=parseFloat(this.AcademicLevels.price);

            var work_level_price= this.calculatePercentage(
                base_price,10
            );

            var unit_price=Number(parseFloat(base_price + work_level_price));
            var amount =(unit_price*2);

            var sub_total =(amount);

            var total= sub_total;

            return total;

        }

    }
```

**The total price display card**

Total price
   $ {{calculateTotal }}

I would appreciate if anyone can help me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on a computed you write

```
 var base_price=parseFloat(this.AcademicLevels.price);
```

in this line `this.AcademicLevels` is an array and you can't access price property to solve this problem in the method that is bined to the button you need to pass the index of array that clicked and then in the computed you need to access the array element at that index and calculated the prices for that the refactored code should looks like this:

template code:

```
<div class="rc-orderform__row">
   <div class="rc-orderform__feature-heading">Academic level</div>
   <div class="rc-orderform__feature-body">
      <div class="rc-validation-representer valid" data-invalid="false">
         <div class="rc-radios rc-radios--theme-default vertical-on-small"   style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <div class="radio-button-wrapper radio-button-wrapper radio-button-wrapper--flexbuttons"  v-for="(academic, index) in AcademicLevels"
               :key="academic.id"
               >
               <button type="button" class="radio-button radio-button--n-1" tabindex="-1"
                  v-on:click="worklevelChanged(index)"
                  :class="academicPriceId===Number(academic.id)? 'active':''"
                  :id="'workLevel_' + academic.id"
                  :value="academic.id"
                  v-model="academicPrice"
                  >
                  <div class="button-checkbox"></div>
                  <div class="radio-button__content">{{academic.name}}</div>
               </button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

the mthod:

```
methods: {
       
        worklevelChanged(selectedIndex){          
            this.selectedPrice = selectedIndex
        }

    },
```

and the computed should be like this:

```
computed:{

        calculateTotal : function (){
            var workLevelModel = this.AcademicLevels;
            var base_price=parseFloat(this.AcademicLevels[this.selectedPrice].price);

            var work_level_price= this.calculatePercentage(
                base_price,10
            );

            var unit_price=Number(parseFloat(base_price + work_level_price));
            var amount =(unit_price*2);

            var sub_total =(amount);

            var total= sub_total;

            return total;

        }

    }
```

it should solve the problem

**Edited:**

```
computed:{

        calculateTotal : function (){
            if(!this.selectedPrice || !this.AcademicLevels[this.selectedPrice] ) {
                return 0;
            }
            var workLevelModel = this.AcademicLevels;
            var base_price=parseFloat(this.AcademicLevels[this.selectedPrice].price);

            var work_level_price= this.calculatePercentage(
                base_price,10
            );

            var unit_price=Number(parseFloat(base_price + work_level_price));
            var amount =(unit_price*2);

            var sub_total =(amount);

            var total= sub_total;

            return total;

        }

    }
```

Comment: I get the below error using the above code:

main.js?id=2d399dbcabcd6e0b4ad37f92a18dae19:63593 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'price')

Comment: alireza.2281 did you notice that?

Comment: i have added the edited computed and this should do the work. check if after clicking one of the buttons works correctly or not

Comment: Its working perfectly !I appreciate your input in this.On page load how do I make the first button active without having to click?

Comment: I have noted that it also onclick returns 0 for the first and last element based on your  method above but from the array they are 20 and 50.

Comment: for the initial value you could specify the array index of element that you want to be active, and for the problem on choosing the first and last element i cant find any thing that would produce 0 try adding console.log on results and variable to find the problem

Comment: by the way if the answer helped you please accept the answer

Comment: I have done so .Thank you brother.This solution solves the 0 value on the first element.

  if(!this.selectedPrice || !this.AcademicLevels[this.selectedPrice] ) {
                return this.AcademicLevels[0].price;
            }